# correlation between variables not having the same number of responses

Tags: correlation, missing-data, likert

can I make correlation between two variable, one of them have 40 responses and the second variable have only 35 responses. taking into consideration that both variable are measured by 5 point likert scale, please help?

Comment: You should clarify the circumstances in the question

Comment: Why the difference? This **is** paired data, with 5 responses missing on one variable, is it? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot take separate collections of data and discern a correlation -- the data must occur *in pairs**, where the value of each of the two variables in the pair are associated with a single instance of something (the thing in common, that which makes them a pair - such as pairs of measurements taken on the same individual).

As a result, when the sample sizes differ, this can only occur because sometimes you don't have both values of the pair.

As long as the missingness is not related to the size of the variables, you should be able to compute the correlation on the remaining complete-pairs.

[If the tendency to be missing is associated with one or both of the variables being small or large, then you couldn't just ignore this effect when trying to estimate correlation.]

* barring some sort of correlation might can be inferred from a model without paired data

Comment: the two variable are for the same sample but one variable differ in size because only respondent who agree with a previouse question were required to express their opinion on a five point likert scale. accordingly does this means that the result of the correlation will be valid

Comment: "As long as the missingness is not related to the size of the variables, you should be able to compute the correlation on the remaining complete-pairs." - hmm. If the missingness is associated with deliberately excluding certain people from the analysis on the basis of previous answers, then even if including those people would have changed the results it is arguably okay to calculate the correlation: so long as you state you're estimating the correlation only for the target subpopulation, and not for a wider population that the deliberately excluded respondents are members of.

Comment: It's not possible for me to assert validity on the information available. I've given some conditions that would need to hold in my answer; there's presently no basis here on which to judge if they do. If they were valid, the correlation would be conditional on the conditions for proceeding to the following question

Comment: @silverfish yes - if the second question targets some subgroup (conditions on some variable) then the correlation would be conditional on that.